# Using git completion inside function

Tags: macos, git, zsh, autocomplete

I use ZSH and have git completions working, provided by `brew install git` (installed to `/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions`).

If I `git commit [TAB]`, it will autocomplete paths which have been modified. But instead of calling `git commit` directly, I want to run a specialised `git_com` function (for auto-formatting of commit message among other things) which runs `git commit` under the hood.

Trouble is, by using a function the autocomplete now shows every path in the current directory, not just the valid `git commit` targets.

Is there a way to bring that autocompletion inside my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
_git # Make git completion functions available
compdef _git-commit git_comm # Complete 'git_comm' like 'git commit'
```